# UI5 - VBox is not valid for aggregation footer of ObjectPageLayout

Tags: sapui5

I have an application with a footer which is same for all pages. Until now, I used separate view for this which I attached to the bottoms of the pages. However, now I created two fragments for item details page (Display/Add modes), using the ObjectPageLayout and want to add my footer into both of those. As I understand, I should use fragment instead of View so I rewrote my footer view into fragment so it looks like this:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:f="sap.f"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
>
    <VBox>
        <Text text=""/>
        <Text text=""/>
        <f:Card class="sapUiTinyMargin" height="100px" width="1144px">
            <f:content>
                <VBox width="100%" alignItems="Center">
                    <Text text=""/>
                    <HBox>
                        <Label text="{i18n>needHelp}" />
                        <ToolbarSpacer width="20px" />
                        <Link text="{i18n>contactUs}" href="mailto:xxx.xxx@xxx.com"/>
                    </HBox>
                </VBox>
            </f:content>
        </f:Card>
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

And then I put this fragment into the footer of the ObjectPageLayout, like this

```
<footer>
<core:Fragment fragmentName="xxx.portal.view.Footer" type="XML"/>
 </footer>
```

However, when I try to load the page, I get the error "*Assertion failed: "Element sap.m.VBox#__vbox1" is not valid for aggregation "footer" of Element sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout#nav---connection--ObjectPageLayou*t"

Any idea why is it showing up and what I am doing wrong? I would also like to note that if I use some simpler elements in the footer (such as Toolbar), there is no error and it gets displayed correctly.

Thank you

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout) of ObjectPageLayout, the footer must be of type [`sap.m.IBar`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.IBar), which is implemented by [`Toolbar`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Toolbar). Hence why the toolbar works and [`VBox`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.VBox) does not.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So, if I want to use the footer fragment, I will have to rewrite it from the VBox to the Toolbar?

Comment: All the IBars have a defined height so that Buttons and Text fit nicely.
Do you really need to use the Footer? Or could you use a Splitter like https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveSplitter/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.ResponsiveSplitter

Comment: Thank you - in the end, I created another section in the objectPageLayout and I put the "footer" in there